# Move uploaded photos from library to profile in 500px

Tags: web, publishing, 500px

I use [500px](https://500px.com) as my web photo archive. I've uploaded some photos accidentally in my library instead of my profile.
How can I publish these private photos to my library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in **manage** page, there is a menu in the left side of the webpage.
You can see 3 items:

- All Photos
- Public
- MarketPlace

When you are in All Photos, you can see the private uploaded photos which are in your library.
For moving these photos to your profile or Public, you can simply select them, then drag and drop at *Public* link at your left side menu.